# as soon s i add a divider between 2 items in jquery accordion it goes haywire

Tags: html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

I just skinned jquery UI Accordion. Everything works fine. But as soon as a add a div or a hr between 2 items it goes all wierd
here is my fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/cancerian73/bgkCg/1/

```
.divider{width:100%; height:15px; background-color:#F00;}
```

Answer (score 1):

As described in the [jquery-ui accordion documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/), you must have pair of **header/content** in your markup :

> The markup of your accordion container needs pairs of headers and content panels
>
> [...]
>
> Accordions support arbitrary markup, but each content panel must always be the next sibling after its associated header. See the header option for information on how to use custom markup structures.

Because you are adding elements between header/content pair :

```
<div class="divider"></div>
```

you must use the [header option](http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#option-header). All you need is to specify which elements are headers in your markup and add your content as siblings of those elements.

Have a look in <kbd>[this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bgkCg/2/)</kbd> and tell me if it feet your needs.

Comment: You're welcome! Don't forget to flag answer as accepted if your problem is solved ;)

Comment: I did LPO the very moment I commented. Always give credit and also to know people that this is the right answer that worked.

Comment: You upvoted the answer but you can also accept it by checking the mark beside the answer (on the left under the vote counter - http://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png)